# What is correct input format for using qgis.processing.run("gdal:buildvirtualraster") in Python script for QGIS 3.10?

Tags: pyqgis, gdal

I am struggling to create a virtual raster using a Python script in QGIS 3.10.

Currently I have a script as follow:

```
rasters = [r'Z:\Rasters\raster1.tif', r'Z:\Rasters\raster2.tif']
outfile = r'Z:\Rasters\extracted.vrt'
processing.run("gdal:buildvirtualraster",{'INPUT':rasters,'RESOLUTION':1,'SEPARATE':False,'PROJ_DIFFERENCE':True,'ADD_ALPHA':False,'ASSIGN_CRS':None,'RESAMPLING':0,'SRC_NODATA':'','OUTPUT':outfile})
```

I also have a newline separated rasters.txt file with the contents as:

```
Z:\Rasters\raster1.tif
Z:\Rasters\raster2.tif
```

Which I pass to the function as:
`rasters = [r'Z:\Rasters\raster1.tif', r'Z:\Rasters\raster2.tif'] outfile = r'Z:\Rasters\extracted.vrt' rasters = r'Z:\Rasters\rasters.txt'  processing.run("gdal:buildvirtualraster",'INPUT':rasters,'RESOLUTION':1,'SEPARATE':False,'PROJ_DIFFERENCE':True,'ADD_ALPHA':False,'ASSIGN_CRS':None,'RESAMPLING':0,'SRC_NODATA':'','OUTPUT':outfile})`

I have also tried passing the contents of rasters.txt to the function as a string in the format:

```
rasters = r"'Z:\Rasters\raster1.tif','Z:\Rasters\raster2.tif'"
```

For all of these I am getting "Incorrect parameter value for INPUT" errors.  I also can't seem to find any information on what a correct parameter value for input should be.

Answer (score 3):

I used your first version of script with my own paths and it works. I only changed 'run' method for 'runAndLoadResults' instead.

```
rasters = [r'/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/raster1.tif', r'/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/raster2.tif']
outfile = r'/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/extracted.vrt'

parameters = {'INPUT':rasters,
              'RESOLUTION':1,
              'SEPARATE':False,
              'PROJ_DIFFERENCE':True,
              'ADD_ALPHA':False,
              'ASSIGN_CRS':None,
              'RESAMPLING':0,
              'SRC_NODATA':'',
              'OUTPUT':outfile}

processing.runAndLoadResults("gdal:buildvirtualraster", parameters)
```

After running above script, result obtained was:

[image]

However, with 'SEPARATE':True and 'ADD_ALPHA' : False options activated (better options in my opinion):

```
rasters = [r'/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/raster1.tif', r'/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/raster2.tif']
outfile = r'/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/extracted.vrt'

parameters = { 'ADD_ALPHA' : False, 
               'ASSIGN_CRS' : None, 
               'EXTRA' : '', 
               'INPUT' : rasters, 
               'OUTPUT' : outfile, 
               'PROJ_DIFFERENCE' : False, 
               'RESAMPLING' : 0, 
               'RESOLUTION' : 0, 
               'SEPARATE' : True, 
               'SRC_NODATA' : '' }

processing.runAndLoadResults("gdal:buildvirtualraster", parameters)
```

result obtained was:

[image]